# ionic 3: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: ionic-framework, gradlew

I am trying to create Android App Bundle for an ionic 3 project. When running the command **./gradlew bundle** I get the error below. In the **.bash_profile** file I have added the following:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/dome/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH/:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

The Gradle version is: 4.4.1.

**ERROR**

```
iMac:android dome$ ./gradlew bundle

> Configure project :app
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The onesignal-gradle-plugin MUST be before com.android.application!
   Please put onesignal-gradle-plugin first OR update to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 or newer!
An exception occurred while trying to find the Android build tools.
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/dome/myAPP/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 121

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Unable to determine Android SDK directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
iMac:android dome$
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding the exports below, I didn't close and reopen the terminal hence the issues. Now sorted.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/dome/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH/:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```